# MySQLi SUM function with pound/dollar sign?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, currency

Within my Admin panel, I would like to see all profits and sales by Weekly, Monthly, Yearly and Total.

So far I am able to display the transactions recorded in the `ap_payment_logs` database in to an advanced responsive table. Above this is where I am trying to display the profits for each margin: Weekly, Monthly Yearly and Total. By selecting and calculating the column: `txn_amount`.

This all works with normal numbers added to that column, although the way my site works, it adds a Pound sign `(£)` before the digits:

`£10.00, £20.00, £50.00...`

The `SUM` function doesn't seem to work with this Pound sign, so I am wondering if there is any simple way to perform the same calculations which would work for this? Here is my current code:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT SUM(txn_amount) AS value_sum FROM `ap_payment_logs` WHERE `txn_date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY'); 
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
                $sum = $row['value_sum'];
                echo $sum;
```

Please Note: I cannot remove the addition of the `£` sign to achieve my results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using real numbers instead of varchars for a number.... unless you remove that `£` it is a string of characters that cannot be treated as a number because it isn't one

Comment: I would rather not have to go through thousands of lines of code to make that kind of change if it can be helped. But if not, it may look like I might have to.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT('$', SUM(txn_amount)) AS value_sum
FROM `ap_payment_logs`
WHERE `txn_date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY

Comment: If you don't you'll be hitting more and more problems in the future; you might be able to create workrounds, but they simply add overhead and complexity to the code, and you'll need more and more workrounds in the future

Comment: You think it'll be best to just remove the pound sign all together and change to an INT ?

Comment: Monetary values should always be stored as integer (minimum units, ie pence) to reduce floating point accuracy issues; and only formatted with decimals and currency symbol for display purposes

Comment: two solution, if u want to save this sign, than u can use html code like &#163; second solution, is that, if you not insert this value in db than concat in your query.

Comment: Okay will look in to it, cheers for the advice!

Comment: SELECT SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(txn_amount, '£', ''), '$', ''))) as value_sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a Table like this:

```
create table dummy (
   id int primary key auto_increment, 
   test varchar(10)
);
```

and these rows in the table:

```
mysql> select * from dummy;
+----+---------+
| id | test    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 10.0    |
|  2 | 14.0    |
|  3 | €14.0   |
+----+---------+
```

you could get the sum of the test values with the following select statement:

```
select sum(replace(test, '€', '')) from dummy;
```

Anyway like Mark Baker I would recommend to store your numeric colums in numeric fields as this has a couple of advantages (aggregates like `sum` are easier, sorting works...).